# Is there a Ruby gem or library that provides a way to parse ordinal numbers?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for a way to parse ordinal numbers (first, second, third, etc) in Ruby and convert them to integers. Do you know of any libraries that do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was half-way through asking this question when I realized that the [`chronic`](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem does this as part of the process of parsing dates. After installing the gem, you can convert ordinal numbers to integers pretty easily:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'chronic'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Chronic::Numerizer.numerize("eighty-fifth").to_i
=> 85
```

---

**Edit:** Unfortunately, it seems that `chronic` doesn't correctly parse the ordinal "second":

```
irb(main):003:0> Chronic::Numerizer.numerize("twenty-second").to_i
=> 20
```

The reason for this is that `chronic` is designed to parse dates and times, and "second" could be either an ordinal number or a unit of time in that context. To solve this problem, you can monkey patch `chronic`'s `Numerizer` class with this line:

```
Chronic::Numerizer::ORDINALS.insert(1, ['second', '2'])
```

Now it works:

```
irb(main):005:0> Chronic::Numerizer.numerize("eighty-second").to_i
=> 82
```

If you are actually using `chronic` for its intended purpose though, you probably won't want to screw with its internals. In that case, you can copy the [source code](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/blob/master/lib/chronic/numerizer.rb) from `Chronic::Numerizer` into a new class and use that one instead. Don't forget to add `['second', '2']` to the `ORDINALS` constant in the new class.

Comment: Great job on answering your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a gem called [numerouno](http://rubygems.org/gems/numerouno) which seems to be specifically targeted at this, if Chronic doesn't fit your use case.

Comment: That only seems to handle cardinal numbers (one, two, three, etc), not ordinal numbers (first, second, third). Still seems pretty useful though.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a gem called deordinalize (https://rubygems.org/gems/deordinalize) which seems to do the trick nicely - just make sure you downcase before calling;

```
>> require 'deordinalize'
>> 'Forty-Second'.downcase.deordinalize
=> 42
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly parse the ordinal "second":
you have now to monkey patch Numerizer class with this line

```
SINGLE_ORDINALS.insert(1, ['second', 2])
```